# How to save fingerprint data in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, fingerprint

So I have a project where I have a model called Beneficiary where I need to store the fingerprint.

This is the model:

```
class Beneficiary(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='home/images/',blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,default='male')
    dob=models.DateField()
    registration_date=models.DateField()
```

I want to save the fingerprints of the beneficiaries in the model.
I am using DigitalPersona2 fingerprint sensor.
I am pretty new to fingerprints so can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about DigitalPersona2, but generally, the Fingerprint device should come with an SDK, that must be installed on the system that uses the fingerprint scanner device. DigitalPersona2 would have an SDK API that would allow you to communicate with the device.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can change my fingerprint sensor. Can you tell me how it is done with your preferred fingerprint sensor.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with your fingerprint sensor of choice, the problem is you don't know how to interact with it.

Comment: Check out the resources below:  https://github.com/hidglobal/digitalpersona-devices

Comment: https://hidglobal.github.io/digitalpersona-devices/tutorial.html